# Div encompasses nav when floated

Tags: html, css, css-float

Why is it that the content div stretches to include the menu nav in this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/kePCS/

If I remove the float property on nav it doesn't. Since the nav width is set to 100% it still seems to be the same size when i inspect it.

I have to have it floated afaik. It's an integral part of this menu that im using http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/beautiful-css-centered-menus-no-hacks-full-cross-browser-support

But i still don't want the nav to sit on top of content that should be below. Do you know any workaround? I wouldn't mind an explanation as to why this happens either. I thought since they were both 100% width they wouldn't overlap. Obviously i was wrong. Thanks!

Won't let me post without code, but the fiddle will be easier to understand.

```
#menu {
float:left;
width:100%;
}
#content{
width:100%;
background-color:#5FC0CE;
}​
```

Comment: is this you want http://jsfiddle.net/ZMrSN/ ??

Comment: Floating the content left works as in the first comment. I'll try that. Unless another answer detailing why i shouldn't do that comes along :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating the content will work, but I personally wouldn't. This is because floating tends to be the source of many IE bugs, and has some more subtle implications that might come back to bite you later.

There's not necessarily a right or wrong way to do this; however, I would instead add a "clear:both;" to #content, which will prevent it from bleeding up into the nav.

Comment: Clear:both seems to be the better alternative. I will use that one. If i add a #content2 later on i would have to float it left as well or it seems the same problem will arise again. This is probably just the nature of floats and im not very used to them. I might have been unclear in my question as well but this is the behaviour i wanted. jsfiddle here if you want to try it for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/kePCS/5/

Comment: Floats were a bit of a mystery to me until I came across this (I highly recommend skimming it at least): http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/19/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/